# how to yield a parsed item from one link with other parsed items from other links in the same item list

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

The problem is that I've been iterating from a list of places to scrape the latitude longitude and elevation. The thing is when I get what I scraped back I have no way to link it with my current df since the names that I iterated may have either been modified or skipped.

I've managed to get the name of what I looked but since its parsed from an outside the link from the rest of the items it doesn't work properly.

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
from ..items import latlonglocItem


df = pd.read_csv('wine_df_final.csv')
df = df[pd.notnull(df.real_place)]
real_place = list(set(df.real_place))


class latlonglocSpider(scrapy.Spider):


    name = 'latlonglocs'
    start_urls = []


    for place in real_place:
        baseurl =  place.replace(',', '').replace(' ', '+')
        cleaned_href = f'http://www.google.com/search?q={baseurl}+coordinates+latitude+longitude+distancesto'
        start_urls.append(cleaned_href)



    def parse(self, response):

        items = latlonglocItem()

        items['base_name'] = response.xpath('string(/html/head/title)').get().split(' coordinates')[0]
        for href in response.xpath('//*[@id="ires"]/ol/div/h3/a/@href').getall():
            if href.startswith('/url?q=https://www.distancesto'):
                yield response.follow(href, self.parse_distancesto)
            else:
                pass
        yield items

    def parse_distancesto(self, response):
        items = latlonglocItem()

        try:
            items['appellation'] = response.xpath('string(/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/p/strong)').get()
            items['latitude'] = response.xpath('string(/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td)').get()
            items['longitude'] = response.xpath('string(/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td)').get()
            items['elevation'] = response.xpath('string(/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[10]/td)').get()
            yield items
        except Exception:
            pass
#output
 appellation      base_name       elevation    latitude    longitude
                  Chalone, USA
 Santa Cruz, USA                  56.81        35           9.23
```

what is happening is that I parse what I looked for then it goes inside a link and parses the rest of the information. However, evidently on my dataframe I get the name of what I looked for completely unattached with the rest of the items and even then is hard to find the match. I wish to pass the info to the other function so it yields all the items all together.

Comment: What is `latlonglocItem()`?

Comment: latlongItem() is calling an item list. which is basically setting up the dataframe with the columns names to be populated after.

Comment: And you can splice the name when you are getting lat, long, and elev?  Do you have an example response you could add?

Comment: the thing is by the time it goes inside the link whatever I parsed is not necessarily what I looked for to begin with. That's why I parsed it outside before going inside but then I have this problem that the items don't come align with the name that I looked for in the beggining.

Comment: `items['base_name']` does not change for all lat/longs right? You could put your methods in a class and make a class variable for `base_name` or use a global variable. (I would recommend class before global). I can give you some example code if that would work.

Comment: this is part of a class. I just sliced the code down, let me put it all so you can see. since the class is specific to this framework called scrapy I don't know if it will allow it but I'm open to try thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work. I will comment both what I am doing and a little bit of your code you have an understanding of what I am doing.

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
from ..items import latlonglocItem


df = pd.read_csv('wine_df_final.csv')
df = df[pd.notnull(df.real_place)]
real_place = list(set(df.real_place))


class latlonglocSpider(scrapy.Spider): # latlonglocSpider is a child class of scrapy.Spider

    name = 'latlonglocs'
    start_urls = []

    for place in real_place:
        baseurl =  place.replace(',', '').replace(' ', '+')
        cleaned_href = f'http://www.google.com/search?q={baseurl}+coordinates+latitude+longitude+distancesto'
        start_urls.append(cleaned_href)

    def __init__(self): # Constructor for our class
        # Since we did our own constructor we need to call the parents constructor
        scrapy.Spider.__init__(self)
        self.base_name = None # Here is the base_name we can now use class wide

    def parse(self, response):

        items = latlonglocItem()

        items['base_name'] = response.xpath('string(/html/head/title)').get().split(' coordinates')[0]
        self.base_name = items['base_name'] # Lets store the base_name in the class
        for href in response.xpath('//*[@id="ires"]/ol/div/h3/a/@href').getall():
            if href.startswith('/url?q=https://www.distancesto'):
                yield response.follow(href, self.parse_distancesto)
            else:
                pass
        yield items

    def parse_distancesto(self, response):
        items = latlonglocItem()

        try:
            # If for some reason self.base_name is never assigned in
            # parse() then we want to use an empty string instead of the self.base_name

            # The following syntax means use self.base_name unless it is None or empty
            # in which case just use and empty string.
            base_name = self.base_name or "" # If for some reason

            items['appellation'] = response.xpath('string(/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/p/strong)').get()
            items['latitude'] = response.xpath('string(/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td)').get()
            items['longitude'] = response.xpath('string(/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td)').get()
            items['elevation'] = response.xpath('string(/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[10]/td)').get()
            yield items
        except Exception:
            pass
```

Comment: I have never seen a `for` loop inside a class but outside a method so I don't know if this will act a little funky.

Comment: It did and didn't work :).
what you did was very helpful now I'm able to get a base_name align to the rest but the base_name doesn't match at all, I will keep trying maybe I got a put it inside the for loop I'm not sure. But you certainly helped me a lot, now I have many more doors open to try. I can't upvote you cuz not enough rep.

Comment: @BB No problem. Good luck :)

Comment: you can look how I modified your answer for it to work. I had to place base_name inside the loop and set concurrent requests from 13 to 1 to work. otherwise the base_name wouldn't match the rest. thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
from ..items import latlonglocItem


df = pd.read_csv('wine_df_final.csv')
df = df[pd.notnull(df.real_place)]
real_place = list(set(df.real_place))


class latlonglocSpider(scrapy.Spider): # latlonglocSpider is a child class of scrapy.Spider

    name = 'latlonglocs'
    start_urls = []

    for place in real_place:
        baseurl =  place.replace(',', '').replace(' ', '+')
        cleaned_href = f'http://www.google.com/search?q={baseurl}+coordinates+latitude+longitude+distancesto'
        start_urls.append(cleaned_href)

    def __init__(self): # Constructor for our class
        # Since we did our own constructor we need to call the parents constructor
        scrapy.Spider.__init__(self)
        self.base_name = None # Here is the base_name we can now use class wide

    def parse(self, response):

        for href in response.xpath('//*[@id="ires"]/ol/div/h3/a/@href').getall():

            if href.startswith('/url?q=https://www.distancesto'):
                self.base_name = response.xpath('string(/html/head/title)').get().split(' coordinates')[0]

                yield response.follow(href, self.parse_distancesto)
            else:
                pass

    def parse_distancesto(self, response):
        items = latlonglocItem()

        try:
            # If for some reason self.base_name is never assigned in
            # parse() then we want to use an empty string instead of the self.base_name

            # The following syntax means use self.base_name unless it is None or empty
            # in which case just use and empty string.
            items['base_name'] = self.base_name or "" # If for some reason
            items['appellation'] = response.xpath('string(/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/p/strong)').get()
            items['latitude'] = response.xpath('string(/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td)').get()
            items['longitude'] = response.xpath('string(/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td)').get()
            items['elevation'] = response.xpath('string(/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[10]/td)').get()
            yield items
        except Exception:
            pass
```

thanks to Error - Syntactical Remorse. Concurrent requests had to set to 1 for it to work and placed base_name inside the loop.